# Given a Scene, find the owning JFXPanel

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

JFXPanels allow you to put JavaFX components into your Swing applications. 
Is there a way, aside from keeping my own map, to get a reference back to the JFXPanel. i.e.

```
javafx.scene.Scene fxScene = ...;

JFXPanel panel = new JFXPanel();
panel.setScene(fxScene);
```

later on...

```
fxScene.getParentJFXPanel(); //this method doesn't exist, but it's what I'm looking for
```

I can kludge something together to get this to work, but I'm hoping the built in libraries have a clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong but a scene is almost like a picture so you can't the JFxpanel if the JFxPanel is just "painting" the scene with the setScene() method.

I'm probably wrong; I know little to no  javafx I deal more with swing.

Comment: A Scene is kind of the JavaFX equivalent of a swing RootPane